# How to write a "balanced" sql select query

Tags: mysql, sql

Forgive me if the title of this question is unclear as I'm struggling to find a name for what I'm looking for. So please bear with me as I explain:

Let's say I have the following tables:

[image]

Now let's say there are 5 entries in `feeds` table:

`the great splog` which publishes 100 posts a day

`unknown blog 1` to `unknown blog 4` which publish 1 or 2 post(s) a day

We are going to fetch these feeds periodically and save their posts in `posts` table.

But then, if I `select` the last 10 entries from `posts` table, there is a big chance that all the 10 posts belong to `the great splog`, simply because it published more posts today than other 4 unknown guys.

**But I don't want 10 posts from the same feed, I want the `select` query to understand this situation and pick -for example- only 2 entries written by `the great splog` and 8 entries written by other unknown blogs from `posts` table.**

**How do you go implementing such a query?**

Comment: You first need to understand yourself what you want your algorithm / query to do. You do not seem to know it yourself as is demonstrated by "I want the select query to understand this situation and pick -for example-..." You need to have cold hard rules and then we can help you to implement them.

Comment: @Tony . . . You need to better clarify what you want.  If you said you wanted 10 posts from different feeds I would understand how to approach the problem.  If you said that you want a random sampling of posts, I would understand.  But how do you come out with the magic number 2?

Comment: One way to do it would be to put a limit on the maximum number or proportion of posts one blog can have in the feed. Is there any way at all that you can know what are the user preferences on this matter ? Does the user prefer blog X over blog Y ? That could help you design some rules.

Comment: Alexandre: maybe I understand the question, it is straightforward. However, Tony: is it necessary to find one _single_ sql-statement? the problem, could be broken into 2 parts and this would be a pretty easy implementation. first count number of feeds/ second select for each feed your desired amount of posts

Comment: Enno, the problem is that OP does not even know himself yet how the output should be divided. This is the question that needs to be solved before implementing anything at all.

Comment: Gordon: the magic number 2 is there as an example. It's just there to show that I don't want all the posts from 1 feed.

Comment: Alexander: My apologies if the question is not clear. There is no known user preferences here. Just that the result of the select query should be "distributed" between all feeds, and not just 1 feed.

Comment: Enno: Thanks for trying to understand my question. It doesn't have to be a single sql statement, but the less the better.

Comment: Ok, Tony please try to be more precise concerning this distribution between all feeds: do you want to get the same amount of latest posts from each feed, regardless how many posts in total came from it?

Comment: Enno: the thing is, I like to be open to suggestions. What is the best practice in such situations? I have a page with "10 recent posts from all blogs", but all the 10 posts are from the great splog, because it has more posts than other blogs. This looks stupid in my part. What would people do in these kind of situations? Do they just show 10 posts from the great splog and be done with it? Or do they try to come up with some "intelligent" solution to also show some posts from other blogs.

Comment: If you just want 1 post per feed, then I humbly suggest: just take the last post from the last 10 active blogs :-)

Comment: Enno: ok, Or I'll take Gordon's suggestion. But I'm still wondering what is the best practice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take 3 diferent, and 7 additional:

```
(SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id IN (SELECT MAX(post_id) FROM posts GROUP BY post_feed_id) ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 3)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 7)
ORDER BY post_id DESC
```

**UPDATE:**
Above code only gives 9, so do some more capsuling to get limit on the right place.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM 
    (
        (
            SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id IN (
                SELECT MAX(post_id) FROM posts GROUP BY post_feed_id
                ) ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 3
        )
        UNION
        (
            SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY post_id DESC
        )
    ) AS temp LIMIT 10
) AS temp2 ORDER BY post_id DESC;
```

Comment: not sure if it always returns 10, or if i should move the 2nd limit outside somewhere

Comment: Thanks, but running this query gives the following error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY post_feed_id) ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 3) UNION (SELECT * FROM pos' at line 1`, any idea why?

Comment: yes, i forgot to add a FROM betwen that SELECT and GROUP BY, see update

Comment: Yes it works now, thanks. I am going to play around with this query.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last post from each feed using this statement:

```
select p.*
from posts p join
     (select p.post_feed_id, max(p.post_id) as maxpi
      from posts p
      group by p.post_feed_id
     ) pf
     on p.post_id = pf.maxpi;
```

Before you can think about getting more than one, you have to think about how you want to allocate them across the feeds.

Comment: Excellent, that will do it for now, Thanks. Now what would you suggest as best practice if i need more than 1 post per feed? As I was explaining for Enno:  I have a page with "10 recent posts from all blogs", but all the 10 posts are from the great splog, because it has more posts than other blogs. This looks stupid in my part. What would people do in these kind of situations? Do they just show 10 posts from the great splog and be done with it? Or do they try to come up with some "intelligent" solution to also show some posts from other blogs?

Comment: @Tony . . . I don't actually know if there is a best practice in this regard.  My suggestion is that you try out either the 10 most recent overall or the ten of the most recent for each blog and move on to other problems in the application you are developing.  You can always return to this problem later, if your initial solution doesn't work.

Comment: Gordon: I'm actually done with my applications and this problem is bugging me :-) In reality i have thousands of feeds, so "10 most recent overall" may return all 10 posts from 1 particular feed. But thanks for your suggestions and query, I will tweak it and play around with it.